# Create a transparent HTML cursor

Tags: javascript, html, cursor

Is it possible to create a transparent HTML cursor on a web page? I'm using a div as a cursor, and I want to make the div 50% transparent: http://jsfiddle.net/mCgmP/16/

```
<div id="cursor"><font size="6">I want this cursor to be 50% transparent!</font></div>
```

Comment: It appears that someone copied this question onto their blog: http://www.blogosfera.co.uk/2013/04/create-a-transparent-html-cursor/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
#cursor
{
opacity:0.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */

}
```

[Here's a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mCgmP/17/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for:

```
#cursor{background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);}
```

Including text:

```
#cursor{background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);}
```

Comment: Will this make the entire div transparent, or will it only make the div's background transparent? I'm actually trying to find a way to make the entire cursor transparent (including the cursor's background).

Comment: The text also?    #cursor{background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);}